# How to determine hole placement on a flat surface in an engineering drawing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad

[image: CAD drawing]

I am to model this part in CAD, but I am unsure as to how the hole spacing on the plate is constrained. Is there something I am failing to see in this drawing that defines the hole placements?

[image]

Comment: Write "field fit" on it and move on.  Or make up a dimension, obviously the original drafter didn't care or forgot.

Comment: Will those hole placements be critical? as long as they are sufficiently clear of the pipe so a screwdriver can get to them then "close" to the corners of the plate should be fine. It is positioning the pipework correctly then drilling the holes in the supporting wall or beam that is more critical.

Comment: Their position is not defined on the drawing - the drawing isn't checked/approved yet, though - so you shouldn't be working from it anyway! Hopefully the check process will spot this error and the dimensions will be added.

Comment: Not asked, but that's not the only thing which seems to need some attention. Placing the mounting plate partially inside the wall of the pipe can inspire some discussions. Hopefully the pipe is not used to conduct any liquid or gas.

Comment: @TigerGuy That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @user287001 This part is meant for a 3D printed model of a flushable toilet. The pipe does not need to be structurally sound as the only thing going through it will be about 300mL of water at virtually zero pressure.

Comment: That's OK if a real waterpipe will be never made by cutting at first a hole to the pipe and then trying to fix it by welding a planar mounting plate.

Answer (score 2):

The hole locations are not dimensioned. You should send the drawing back for clarification.

It's hard to imagine a scenario where estimating or, doing something jankey like measuring the drawing would be appropriate. Making a part wrong, then having to modify or remake it is a lot harder than just making a 5 minute phonecall for clarification.

Now with all that said, I realize this is almost certainly homework; due to the non-sensible design, and the fact that you're 3D modeling a drawing which was clearly generated in CAD. Regardless it's good prep for the real world because these kinds of mistakes occur all the time.

Comment: Ok yeah, I thought so. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't being an idiot and was missing a constraint or inference somewhere.